# Linear matrix equation of the form $AX=B+AXC$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, matrix-equations

> Solve the following equation for matrix $X$. $$ \begin{bmatrix} 2 & 3 \\ 1 & 2 \end{bmatrix} X = \begin{bmatrix} 1 & 1 & 0  \\ 0 & 1 & 1 \end{bmatrix}+\begin{bmatrix} 2 & 3 \\ 1 & 2 \end{bmatrix}X\begin{bmatrix} 0 & 1 & 1 \\ 0 & 0 & 1 \\ 0 & 0& 0\end{bmatrix}\ $$

---

So this has the form of $AX=B+AXC$. I've tried moving the $A$ on the left side to the right side with the inverse. Then you can move the $XC$ to the left side. So you get something like $X−XC=A^{−1}B$. After this point I'm stuck and uncertain what to do or if I did the above correctly.

Edit:
So the answer I got with the commented suggestion was [(2,1,0),(-1,0,1)]. Is that correct?

Comment: For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [here](/help/notation), [here](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [here](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [here](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: Go on! $X=A^{-1}B(I_3-C)^{-1}.$

Comment: Did you factor out X to get (I−C)?

Comment: The first step is to realize that it's a linear system with 6 equations and 6 unknowns.

Comment: Once you have a guess for X, you can simply substitute it into your equation and check if it is correct

Comment: @Hyperplane can you explain what you mean? Is there some way to just brute force this into an AX = b form?

Comment: @Dewlynjones Yes! One approach is by [vectorization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vectorization_(mathematics)). One can use the identity $AXB^⊤ = (B⊗A)⋅\operatorname{vec}(X)$, where $⊗$ is the [kronecker-product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kronecker_product).

Answer (score 2):

$AX=B+AXC$

$AX-AXC=B$

$A(X-XC)=B$

$(X-XC)=A^{-1}B$

$X(1-C)=A^{-1}B$

Note that $1$ represents the $3\times3$ identity matrix.

$X=A^{-1}B(1-C)^{-1}$

$$ X=\begin{pmatrix} 2 & 3 \\ 1&2 \end{pmatrix}^{-1} \begin{pmatrix} 1 & 1 &0 \\ 0&1 & 1 \end{pmatrix}\left[\begin{pmatrix} 1&0&0 \\ 0&1&0 \\ 0&0&1 \end{pmatrix}-\begin{pmatrix} 0&1&1 \\ 0&0&1 \\ 0&0&0 \end{pmatrix}\right]^{-1}$$

Now by simplifying this, you will get the value of X. the X will be a $2*3$ matrix

Comment: 1) The 3 first steps were already done by the OP (original poster). 2) better denote the $3\times3$ identity matrix by $I_3$, like in the comment above. 3) Don't write $(I_3-C)^{-1}$ *before* justifying that $I_3-C$ is invertible. 4) Put an $\iff$ sign at each step. 5) There is nothing to "simplify" at the end: just calculate. 6) The size of the matrix $X$ (mandatory for the equation to make sense) should rather be mentionned at the beginning.

Comment: ${\tt+1}$ But for greater generality use pseudoinverses  
$$ \large X = A^+\,B\;(I-C)^+ $$